# libnss-mysql gone in Jessie?

Tags: mysql, debian, ldap, nss

I was happily using libpam-ldap and libnss-mysql (authenticating clients directly against LDAP, with NSS data such as UID/GID/home dir kept in a mysql database).

Now I tried to install Jessie on clients, but libnss-mysql is gone from Debian Jessie. What happened to it? The project is still hosted on sourceforge -- which seems to be evil now -- and there's no activity. It's also not in backports.

Is there a functional replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question the reasons given for removing it from debian were

- Ophaned since 1.5 years
- Dead upstream (former maintainer is also the Savannah
  project admin)
- Virtually unused

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617591

Seems the last reelase it was in was squeeze, it wasn't in wheezy or jessie.

The second part of your question is harder. Some googling found libnss-mysql-bg but that isn't in jessie or stretch either and while it is in sid the sid version has a rather nasty looking rc bug.